# Getting "bus error 10" error message?

Tags: c, pointers

```
  char *name= "tony";
  name[2] = 'z';
  printf("%s",name);
```

why does this give me a bus error 10? and what does it mean?
This book tells me its because "tony" string literal is saved in read only memory and you can't alter it, but i don't understand because i can do things like this..

```
  char *name= "tony";
  name = "another";
  printf("%s",name);
```

In this case i just changed the read only memory and it works fine.
Thanks pointer give me a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *name= "tony";
name = "another";
printf("%s",name);
```

In this case you did not change the data in the read only memory. You just made `name` pointer to point to another read only memory (where "another" is stored).

```
char *name= "tony";
name[2] = 'z';
printf("%s",name);
```

In this case, you are actually editing the data stored in the read only memory.

Comment: I see, so did i create another array called "another" and store it in stack?

Comment: Its not another array. Its another string literal stored in some other place in the read only memory.

Comment: so the only way to store a string literal in stack is to use `char name[]`?

Comment: @Charana String literals aren't stored on the stack. The contents of the string literal are *copied* into the array (which is stored on the stack) when you use `char name[]`.

Comment: A weird realisation is starting to hit me,So when i do `char name[] ="tony"` ,tony is stored as a string literal in read only memory and is also made into an array for editing.In the case of `char *name = "tony"`,tony is again stored in read only memory but now a pointer points to it in read only memory.

Comment: @ameyCU so `char name[] ="tony"` will just create something on stack

Comment: @Charana  Yes but not something but char array .

Answer (score 2):

```
char *name= "tony";
```

String literal `"tony"` is in read-only memory .It is a constant . You can't modify it . It means you can't do this -

```
name[0]='a';         // this should not be done
```

OTOH -

```
char *name= "tony";
name = "another";     // no problem will execute correctly
```

You only change where the pointer `name` points to .This is valid because pointer is not constant .

So , you can't modify the literal but you can change  what the pointer `name` points to.

Well , if you declare like this -

```
char name[]="tony";
name[2] = 'z';           // completely valid
printf("%s",name);
```